# Entity Framework Core how to execute migrations in production environment

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

We are developing a desktop application with Entity Framework Core v.2.x.x.
During the development we migrate the database via Visual studio package management console and the useful `add-migration` and `update-database` commandlets.
Now the application is ready go in production.
I would like to use the very same commandlets in the production environment so to allow installers to create and udpate the database through the same architecture that has been used and tested in development.
Is it possible? If not, what is the closest alternative?

I've read the following question:
[.Net Core - Entity Framework Core Migrations - Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54259010/net-core-entity-framework-core-migrations-production)
that is a broader view on this topic; unfortunately without answer. I think the approach that i'm suggesting is one of the possible solutions to that problem, that devises attention as specific, stand-alone question.

Comment: I personally don't like using migrations on production. Rather I generate a SQL script from development environment and run that script on production environment.

Answer (score 1):

In our projects we use backup and restore procedure, proven to be the easiest and fastest reliable way of deploying DB to Staging / Production environments, that could also be automated and integrated to the CI/CD process. Depends on your DB server I might help in providing more tips and tricks from our know how process.